# After Deployment SQL Server does not allow folder / file creation within SSIS Script Task

Tags: sql-server, ssis, script-task

I designed a SSIS package that ensures `.CSV` file generation into a destination folder using a Script Task component. Everything is ok when I run from the Visual Studio solution but the problems starts to appear right after deployment in SQL Server. The Script Task shows success but no file is generated. If someone please can provide help.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I'm running the package through Sql job that use my windows account which is an admin account with full control of my OS.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running it through a SQL job? This might be because the SQL Agent account (or whatever account you're running with) might not have Read/Write permissions on that particular directory.